# HTML, CSS: overbar matching square root symbol

Tags: html, css, overlap

Is there a way in HTML4 and/or CSS to do the following, but then correctly:

> √¯¯¯¯¯¯φ·(2π−γ)
>       ↑ ← ←  ←

How can I move my expression to the left, under the `&macr;` symbols, such that they overlap eachother? *Note: it should work on every font-size.*

Thanks!

<sub>(My current code, *thank you Matthew Jones<sup>(+1)</sup> for the `text-decoration: overline`*, lacks the scaling of sizes and correctly positioning the overline. That's why I edited this question, as `&macr;` does match in size & position in the *Georgia* font.)</sub>

Comment: Tip: Start using Latex. As soon as you have fractions etc. under the root symbol, it gets even harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works **exactly** as I wanted it:

```
<div class="math">
    &radic;<span>&macr;&macr;&macr;&macr;</span><span style="margin-left: -2.39em; vertical-align: 0.1em;">x + 1</span>
</div>
```

(Where `math` defines a `font-family: Georgia` and `font-size`)

This works on any font-size! :-)

Example: http://jsbin.com/ihaba3

Comment: This looks horrible in my browser. Chrome 29.

Comment: Looks not "exactly" as asked. It looks shattered. 

Answer (score 4):

You could set the CSS for the text that should appear under the overbar as

`text-decoration:overline`

**EDIT:** This comes pretty darn close to what you want (Chrome 4.1.249):

```
<div style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: 200%">
    <span style="vertical-align: -15%;">&radic;</span>
    <span style="text-decoration: overline; vertical-align:-20%;">&nbsp;x&nbsp;+&nbsp;1&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately there does not appear to be a way to modify the thickness of the overline itself...

Comment: I just tested that on the above example using Firebug and it works *perfectly*!.

Comment: I see (though the enter after the span adds horizontal space, I presume you added it because of formatting on StackOverflow). Though, lowering the expression wasn't my goal, just lowering the bar, the text is at a good position. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: This works perfectly for me if there is no whitespace between the first end span tag and the next start span tag. `</span><span>` http://jsbin.com/utolo You could also use a `border-top` declaration to try and match the thickness and it looks pretty good: http://jsbin.com/utolo/2

Comment: Messed with the vertical-align (setting it to -25%) to make it line up better. Score! http://jsbin.com/utolo/3

Comment: The problem is that when the size is smaller, they don't match up. As I would like to use this as a "container", how big or small it will be, it should always match the root's tail. (For instance, the size will be smaller inside a division than "stand-alone".)

Comment: @Pindatjuh I would make two styles then, large and small (for division)… or more. I don't think it's going to be feasible to code css that will perfectly match the font metrics for the √ symbol regardless of size. http://jsbin.com/utolo/4

Answer (score 2):

you miight be able to put the characters under the root in a seperate span then style it with a border on top. But you'll probably have to increase the font-size of the `&radic;` to make it line up.

Comment: Actually `border-top` works perfectly! Check out this fiddle to compare it to `text-decoration:overline` http://jsfiddle.net/qDZNB/

Answer (score 2):

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <msqrt>
        <mrow>φ(2π−γ)</mrow>
    </msqrt>
</math>
```

Comment: Would be nice if this worked in all current browsers, wouldn't it?

Comment: It'd be nice if people stopped using IE, yes.